# AWS Lambda executed successfully with SQS event trigger but not with SQS test case

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

**This is my code:**

```
        const aws = require('aws-sdk');
        const dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB();
        const sqs = new aws.SQS();
        var item;
        var orderName;
        var orderPrice;
        exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            
          event.Records.forEach(record => {
            const { body } = record;
           item = JSON.parse(body);
            });
            console.log(item);
            
             var orderName = item.OrderName;
             var orderPrice = item.OrderPrice;
            
          var dynamoParams = {
              Item: {
                "OrderName": {
                    S: orderName
                },
                "OrderPrice": {
                  S: orderPrice
                }
              }, 
          ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL", 
          TableName: "Orders"
          };
          
          dynamodb.putItem(dynamoParams, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
          });
};
```

SQS Input Message which triggers this Lambda Function: `{ "OrderName": "Laptop", "OrderPrice": "40000" }`

My Question is Lambda Executed successfully with SQS event trigger but, if I am going to invoke the function with `Test` It is giving me following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
  "trace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
    "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
    "    at /var/task/index.js:15:16",
    "    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:13:17)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Successful SQS Event trigger logs:

[image]

Comment: The message format when invoking from SQS is far more complicated than when directly invoking via the aws console. Log the event as the first thing in your function and compare the two outputs

Comment: Yup!! compared both the events, actual SQS event trigger adds "single quote('')" to the message, with test case manually tried to add the single quote, it says JSON Syntax error while saving test case template